# What would be the logic to find possible combinations for this?

Tags: combinations

Suppose I have five numbers: 12345. I want to split them into 2, 3, 4 and so on possible ways:

If we split into two columns, we have `4` these possibilities:

```
1    | 2345
12   | 345
123  | 45
1234 |  5
```

If we split into three columns, we have `6` these possibilities:

```
 1 | 2   | 345
 1 | 23  | 45
 1 | 234 |  5
12 | 3   | 45
12 | 34  | 5
123| 4   | 5
```

If split into four columns, we have `4` these possibilities:

```
12 |  3 |  4 | 5
 1 | 23 |  4 | 5
 1 |  2 | 34 | 5
 1 |  2 |  3 | 45
```

Split into five columns, we have `1` possibility

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

So, we can split 5 numbers into maximum 5 columns and In total we have 15 possibilities we can split these up.

Just as this representation shown above, is there a mathematical way to count for these possibilities for any number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  If you include the "split" into *one* column, you have a total of $16=2^{5-1}$ possibilities.

Comment: What about if I want to know e.g. in how many ways I can split `12345` into 3 columns as above? Is there a certain rule or concept of maths we are following or we are making it up our own?

Comment: @cpx, to split an ordered list of $n$ objects into $k$ columns, you need to insert $k-1$ column markers in the $n-1$ gaps between consecutive objects.  Note that ${5-1\choose3-1}=6$.

Comment: I couldn't have figured. Just to make sure, are those binomial coefficient in big bracket?

Comment: Yes, those are binomial coefficients.

Comment: @cpx, yes, the key idea is that you get to *choose* where to put the column markers.  (A binomial coefficient $n\choose k$ is normally read as "$n$ choose $k$.")